# Visual Studio Just In Time Debugger: An unhandled Microsoft .Net Framework exception occurred

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, windows-xp

I am trying to find the cause of the following error when I run my WPF application on Windows XP.

> An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in MyProgram.EXE [2672] Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled.  In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time
>
> Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errods' for more information.

I used to have VS2010 running on my XP box but I have uninstalled it.

How do I get more information about what is causing the error?

I am using .Net Framework 4.0 which is installed on the Windows XP machine.

The application runs correctly on Windows 7.

[Update]

The start up object is MyProgram.App

this contains

```
    public partial class App : Application
{

}
```

stepping through on the dev machine takes me to

```
public MainWindow()
        {
           // various controller set up commands
        }
```

on the dev machine I next step into

```
MainWindow_Loaded()
```

however it doesn't make it this far on the XP Machine.

[Update]

I was able to edit the procedure that set up the commands

```
private void WireupCommands()
        {

            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

            this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(MainCommands.AppExit, MainExitCmdExecuted, AlwaysCanExecute));  // etc
         }

static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
        {

            Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace));
         }
```

And this reported the error "Image Format Is UnRecognised" along with a stack trace that barely contained a line of my code.

A solution for this is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385143/wpf-application-shows-image-format-is-unrecognized)

I still get the Just In Time Debugger message after this

Comment: Can you try a modified version of your app? In that case, try to handle AppDomain.UnhandledException event, and log the exception.

Comment: I have the code, the trouble is figuring out where to put the try-catch.  I know from displaying message boxes that the error does not occur in MainWindow()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hooking up the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event during app startup, and use appropriate logging to log the exception. From documentation - "Occurs when an exception is **not** caught." So you don't have to know where to put the `try catch`.. Just log it from the event.